# What are the Key Locker, Beacon and Portal Fracker and how are they useful

Tags: ingress

With the release of the store there are new items that are available for micro-transation purchase only. They are Key Locker, Beacon, and Portal Frackers.

What are they used for and how can I get them?

<sub>For those of you who don't have the store yet, it's coming in an incremental rollout.</sub>

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These 3 items can only be brought from the Ingress store. At this stage they are unobtainable from hacking. I will list the items and go through their uses below.

### Key Locker

- Account bound and undroppable, [only up to 5 per player](https://support.ingress.com/hc/en-us/articles/212572708-Ingress-in-app-store-FAQ).
- 5 different colours which don't affect their stats.
- Functions like a normal capsule except all keys placed in them don't count towards player inventory limit.
- Maximum of 5 Key Lockers per Agent.
- Functionally means that you can have 500 more keys in your inventory that don't count towards your item cap.
- Costs 3700 CMU
- Costs 14900 CMU for 5.

### Beacon

- Account bound and consumable
- Effective for 4 hours.
- Makes a portal it is used on show up on scanners for nearby agents.
- Could be used to organise flash-farms but of limited strategic value.
- Available in Enlightened, Resistance, Target and Meetup beacons.
- Costs 1300 CMU for a pack of 3.

### Portal Fracker

- Account bound and consumable
- Limited to 10 minutes or 150 hacks whichever happens first.
- Causes hacks to provide double the regular number of items per hack. This *INCLUDES* portal keys. **Mods will duplicate but may not have the same rarity.** So if a VRHS is hacked, the duplicate may be a CHS.
- Does not affect portal cooldown or maximum hacks before burnout.
- Costs 2400 CMU for 1.
- Costs 9600 CMU for 5.
- Costs 14900 CMU for 10.
- **Will drain all resonator levels by half after the 10 minute time limit.** This means the portal will need recharging.

Strategies:

If you have lots of keys in your inventory, maybe invest in some Key Lockers. They function just like regular capsules, so you can sort the keys in there by distance or title.

Beacon's might be useful for new players but don't seem to hold any value that good team communication doesn't already provide.

Frackers would be useful for flash-farms where agents are very low on gear. But to make the most of it, there would need to be VRMH, VRHS deployed, so that agents get more than 3 hacks in 10 minutes. Also, to hit 150 hacks with a single VRHS on a portal, you would need 25 agents in the same place. Multiple VRHS's deployed would allow hacking faster than 90 seconds. The usefulness of this item depends heavily on the availability of standing farms in your area.

Storefront:
[image: Storefront 1]
[image: Storefront 2]
[image: Storefront 3]
[image: Storefront 4]
[image: Storefront 5]

<sub>The above information is provided based on the information gained from the Ingress G+. I am just an Enlightened agent in Australia, not anyone from NIA, so recommendations to buy things are my own</sub>

Comment: Beacon is also visible in Ingress intel map. They are mostly for fun anyway.

Comment: Do we can't use keys inside the key locker to link ?

Answer (score 0):

They have recently (In November as I can recall) sold a new beacon type called "Niantic beacon" as a time limited item on the store.

[image]